# Spring AMQP stuck queue due to unack'd message

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am using a SimpleMessageListenerContainer and had problems that every hour or so the queue would get stuck and nothing would be processed due to an unack'd message.

I am sure this is due an error that isn't being caught properly but can't trace the issue.

I have set the acknowledge mode to NONE and this "fixed" the issue but it is really just hiding the issue. Also if I want to throw a AmqpException and re-queue the message this doesn't work with acknowledge mode set to NONE.

My question is how can I trace the issue with the queue getting stuck, is there a way to see the payload of the unack'd message? Or is there an acknowledgement mode that will allow acknowledges to not to be needed but re-queue messages if an exception is thrown?

Here is how I am registering a listener:

```
final SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
container.setQueueNames(queueName);
container.setMessageListener(new MQMessageListenerWrapper(listener));
container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.NONE);
container.start();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried with `channel-transacted="true"` ?

Comment: Would be great if you share the config to reproduce an issue.

Comment: The problem is I can't recreate it in a local environment even when I push through the same messages! I've update the question with code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue within my code that I finally tracked down as it only occurred in a rare instance.

This had nothing to do with Spring AMQP or RabbitMQ just my bad coding :-)

Comment: what was the issue actually? I'm facing the same case.

Comment: @Ashim it was 6 years ago but I think it was due to not acknowledging a message when it went a certain route through the code so was always stuck on the same message.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is your consumer thread is hung someplace upstream of the listener. When control is returned to the container, the message is ack'd or rejected; it can't be left in an unack'd state if the thread returned to the container.

Use `jstack <pid>` to find out where the consumer thread is stuck.

You are correct `NONE` is just masking the issue.

Answer (score 1):

When the queue gets stuck look at the connections listening on the specific queue. Could be a sign of some sort of dead lock scenario because of 2 (or more) consumer-threads listening on the same queue - and therefore being blocked by rabbit.

Comment: I have 2 apps, adding to the queue, and 2 apps reading from the queue. I can't see any deadlocks or how they could occur. I have other apps that don't seem to have this issue which is why I think there might be an exception something I'm not seeing and causing the acknowledge not to happen.